# Square root on specific values in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, square-root

I'm new to python. I'm trying to obtain the square root for 3 of 5 values in my dictionary. I have figured out the square root for 1 value, but not how to pull more. Here is what I've done:

```
import math as mt

#Define dictionary
atomic_mass = {'H': 1, 'C': 12, 'S': 32, 'O': 16, 'N': 7}

mt.sqrt(atomic_mass['S'])  # output: 5.656854249492381
```

But when I try this operation on multiple values, I get errors.

```
mt.sqrt(atomic_mass['C','S','O'])  # KeyError: ('C', 'S', 'O')

mt.sqrt(atomic_mass['C'],['S'],['O'])  # TypeError: sqrt() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

mt.sqrt(atomic_mass['C' and 'S']) #yields only the square root of 'S' = 5.656854249492381
```

Obviously I could find sqrt one at a time, but I'm trying to obtain results for multiple values at a time. Is this possible? Thx

Comment: What do you want to get eventually? Do you want to override `atomic_mass`'s values with square roots or generate new dict? Definetely you have to call `sqrt` function multiple times.

Comment: `sqrt` funtion you use allows only one square root at a time. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html could be good solution, but it requires changing data structures and the whole approach. And it's not very usefull for beginners. There're a lot of other topics to practice. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was trying to get: 3.46410, 5.65685, 4. But am very new and did not realize sqrt only allows one square root at a time. Thanks for the doc and help.

Comment: I'd recommend to pay attention to more basic topics. Looking at your attempts, better if you learn more about python builtin collections, such as `dict` (especially), also `list`, `set`, `tuple`. numpy arrays are kind of python lists, but implemented in C, much faster and more powerfull. It's for scientific calculations with heavy datasets. Not an option for beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Was getting ahead of myself. Will practice on the builtins, usually nights and weekends when not w kids. I did import a random data set from numpy and practicing basic math ops, e.g. mean, median, sum, etc.  numpy import random
import numpy as np
#uniform random numbers in [0,1]
data_one = random.rand(5,5)